# How to get Data in the main array when filtering in the Sub Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I have this data where I filter the vendorId and the user Id of the Product it goes with something like this:

## Code:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 6,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        name: "Product A",
        vendor: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Product B",
        vendor: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Product B",
        vendor: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        name: "Product Aaa",
        vendor: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Product Bbb",
        vendor: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Product Ccc",
        vendor: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const userId = 1;

const filteredData = data.map(({ orderedItems }) => {
  return orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => {
    return vendor == userId;
  });
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

It logs or returns something like this:

```
[
  [
    { name: 'Product A', vendor: 1 },
    { name: 'Product B', vendor: 1 }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Product Alif', vendor: 1 },
    { name: 'Product Baa', vendor: 1 }
  ]
]
```

I want it to return something like this not only ordered Items but something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 6,
    orderedItems: [
      { name: "Product A", vendor: 1 },
      { name: "Product B", vendor: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    orderedItems: [
      { name: "Product Alif", vendor: 1 },
      { name: "Product Baa", vendor: 1 },
    ],
  },
];
```

still filtered but with all the data needed. If you have any questions and clarification needed please comment down below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code.

```
const filteredData = data.map(({ id, orderedItems }) => {
    return {id: id, orderedItems: orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => vendor == userId)};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this is what I needed

Comment: I just have some changes comments here, since the filtered ordered Items returns already but when I dont have a userId it returns the data Id but the orderedItems is empty, how do I also make id empty also.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in the code.

```
const userId = 1;
const filteredData = data.map(({id, orderedItems }) => {
var orderedItems = orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => {
    return vendor == userId;
});
    return  {id, orderedItems}
});  
    
filteredData.forEach( (item, index) => {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I upvoted your answer. This is also what I needed

Comment: I just have some changes comments here, since the filtered ordered Items returns already but when I dont have a userId it returns the data Id but the orderedItems is empty, how do I also make id empty also.